# mongo restore dump from a folder via docker

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

Following this [tutorial](https://blog.studiointeract.com/mongodump-and-mongorestore-for-mongodb-in-a-docker-container-8ad0eb747c62) to restore collections and records from a dump but I'm getting following errors from the docker logs.

> 2019-07-27T12:02:13.857+0000  Failed: error connecting to db server: no
>   reachable servers 2019-07-27T12:02:20.052+0000    Failed: error
>   connecting to db server: no reachable servers

The dump folder is within assets folder.

> assets/dump/mydatabase

```
mongo:
  image: mongo:4.0.10
  container_name: mongo
  restart: always
  volumes:
    - ./assets:/backup
  command:  bash -c "mongorestore /backup --host mongo:27017"
  ports:
    - 27017:27017
    - 27018:27018
    - 27019:27019
```

---

**Edit after discussion**

```
mongo:
  image: mongo:4.0.10
  container_name: mongo
  restart: always
  volumes:
    - ./assets:/backup
  command:  mongorestore /backup
  ports:
    - 27017:27017
    - 27018:27018
    - 27019:27019
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

File structure - assets folder same location as docker-compose in the root

[image]

Comment: Can you try `mongorestore /backup --host ip:27017`

Comment: you mean my local ip 127.0.0.1?

Comment: The command is being run inside the container and as such it does not know what mongo:27017 is all about. Try to either just do mongorestore /backup  or if you want to specify the host, try local host or 127.0.0.1.  On other things, you should be able to skip the bash -c part of the comman pd since you are issuing just one command

Comment: @camba1 please have a look at the Edit section.

Comment: it runs smoothly if i comment out `command: mongorestore /backup`